# NGINX-plus vs NGINX in terms of cost

Tags: nginx

Is NGINX-Plus *freeware* the same as NGINX?

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

You can look at Step 3 of the **Creating NGINX Plus Docker Image** on the page you linked to see that the only free part is a trial you still have to sign up for.

There is a feature matrix available [here](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/#compare-versions) if you want to compare and you can get pricing information [here](https://www.nginx.com/pricing/) if you're interested in purchasing it.